# Top & bottom bars fade in and out during activity transition animation

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm testing my app out on my nexus 5 and every time I transition between activities the bottom and top bars (the native ones) fade out and back in again, revealing the launcher or whatever activity is below for a split second.

Seems to be related to this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WizardActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_exit, R.anim.fade_enter);
```

Anyone know what's happening here and how to fix it while keeping the same animation transition?

This is my fade_exit.xml if it helps diagnose this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"

    android:zAdjustment="top">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The issue had to do with the theme of the activity being set to transparent.